# Quarkus+OpenApi reuseable query parameters with $ref

Tags: java, openapi, quarkus

**Quarkus v3.4.1**

**OpenApi v3.0.3**

I would like to have $ref with 1 model for query parameters.

What I have now:

```
  "paths" : {
    "/s3/upload" : {
      "get" : {
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "ids",
          "in" : "query",
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        } ],
        "responses" : ...
        }
      },
```

What I need is something like this:

```
  "paths" : {
    "/s3/upload" : {
      "get" : {
        "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ParameterListValueObject",
        "responses" : ...
        }
      },
```

I tried so many versions with the annotations, but nothing was similar.

Comment: https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.6/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Parameter.html#ref--

Answer (score 1):

As described in Quarkus ["Using OpenAPI and Swagger UI"](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#loading-openapi-schema-from-static-files) it is possibile to merge autogenerated openapi documentation with static files so the solution is to create a file named `META-INF/openapi.yaml` with this content:

```
components:
  parameters:
    list-of-id:
      in: query
      name: ids
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
```

(note that your file doesn't need to be a complete openapi files,only the parts you need to describe manually).
Than access this ref using `@Parameter(ref = "list-of-ids")`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by defining the parameter separately in the OpenAPI components and using the `ref` property of `@Parameter` on the JAX-RS REST parameter.

```java
@OpenAPIDefinition(
    info = @Info(/* Required info properties */),
    components = @Components(
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                name = "ids",
                in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                schema = @Schema(implementation = String[].class)
            )
        }
    )
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}
```

The parameter definition above can then be referenced with `@Parameter(ref = "ids")` on the REST operation's parameter. Using annotations to set the parameter in `components` limits you to using the same `name` for both the parameter and its key for the entry in `components`, in this example `ids`. If you require the name to be different from the entry's key, you can provide a static OpenAPI file at `/META-INF/openapi.yaml` or `/META-INF/openapi.json` with the parameter defined as you want it, then use `@Parameter(ref = "your-custom-entry-key")`.

Comment: I already tried something similar. But in this solution I will have the $ref, but it will be in an array, and the first parameter will be model, but I'd like to move all parameters to one model. I'm not even sure it is possible. Maybe I should just add manually a @Schema value object somewhere in my code, and let my SDK generator know about the component.

Comment: > I'd like to move all parameters to one model. I'm not even sure it is possible

It's not possible, the parameter list in the OpenAPI spec will always be expanded. If you'd like to have them in one model in your Java code, you can place them all in a POJO (with the JAX-RS annotations on each property) and pass that to your REST method annotated with `@BeanParam`.